# Re size fixed navigation for ipad and iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, resize, nav

i have a fixed navigation on this site displays perfectly on the computer but when i view on the iPad or iPhone the 'contact' section drops down onto the header, I've tried to reduce the navigation padding it then does not display how i want, I've also looked at Jquery re-sizing but it hasn't worked... What do i need to do to stop it dropping down? How can i get it to re-size on the iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Try bootstrap, they have nice simple navbars

Answer (score 0):

[click here](http://bootswatch.com/journal/)

for a template, it's free to use.

Try zooming in, you'll see what happens to the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are beginning (indirectly!) to create a [Responsive web site](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)(Good choice :)).  I think you should introduce some media queries to your design  if you are concern about how your website renders in different screen sizes (Or ViewPort in responsive design terms). You have the option to use a [establish frameworks](http://designinstruct.com/roundups/html5-frameworks/) or simply introduce some media queries and do it yourself. Since your design looks fairly minimal I'd start with creating your own media query just to fix iPad issue with and see where you get with it.  Look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to understand media queries. I hope this answer is useful.Of course if you know more about responsive design this answer might look pointless!

Comment: thank you this looks good, i will look into it! Still learning these things at the min! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mind accepting or up voting the answer if you think this is the answer you were looking for?

Comment: i really don't understand it, no matter what i do, i can't get the navigation to just shrink down slightly on the ipad and iphone.. i  don't want to go all the way of making a mobile website.. i just want the navigation to display along the top without dropping down. At the min it does exactly the same on both the ipad and the iphone so it makes me think it could possibly be something in the nav code rather than using media queries... if that makes any sense! lol

Comment: OK in your case you are using PX try using % instead for padding, margins and width. You'd hopefully find your answer there. Other than that you'd find it difficult fix this issue without using Media queries.

Comment: I've used 2% instead of px - kind of fixes it for now. I will look more into media queries later. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad it'd help you achieve what you were looking. Do you mind accepting the answer then?